# Add softwarerecs to vote to migrate option

Tags: discussion, status-declined, migration

We should include the [Software Recommendations](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com) in the "Vote to migrate" menu. There are a lot of SuperUser questions about software recommendations and it'd be good to put an option.

Also, a lot of questions are "How do I do XYZ" that are basically asking for a software recommendation without outright saying "What is a software that can" and we'd be able to crack down on it more.

Comment: Migrations to beta sites aren't added.

Comment: @Sathya Why not? Just wondering.

Comment: Beta site are still in the definition stage, and there's no guarantee they'll live.

Comment: @Sathya Why not add it until it's removed from the site or beta stage? It'd help the site grow from beta as well.

Comment: http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/5779/can-we-please-add-http-sqa-stackexchange-com-as-a-migration-target/5780#5780

Comment: @chipperyman573 - Even if those questions were allowed to be migrated to a beta website the example template you provided is actually a bad fit for the beta proposal itself.  They don't want software lists, they want suggestions based on actual usage, and honest testimonials that share first hand experience.  Feel free to suggest to those users who to make those off-topic questions here to ask proper questions on the proposal website.

Comment: The site is more mature now. See the new request to re-evaluate this one https://meta.superuser.com/questions/11137/add-softwarerecs-to-the-migration-targets

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Software Recommendations has really just gone public—until yesterday, they didn't even have moderators yet.

When migrating to sites, you want them to be established first. Which means that they've been in beta for a really long time, or that they've gone out of beta already. If you migrate questions to an early beta site, you run the risk of having these questions lost forever if the beta is cancelled.

Furthermore, if a beta site cannot attract traffic on its own and needs questions fed from other sites, that's not a healthy growth either. That's why new sites are "left alone" during their beta period—to see if the idea of the site works out and whether it can survive.

Finally, Software Recommendations does not even have a proper definition of the topics they allow. You will notice that they don't have a real FAQ either. You want to give them time to establish some community norms first before dumping everything from Super User there.

What you *can* do is point people to SR in a comment, but you should also have them [read this](https://softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/455) and [this other](https://softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/336) Meta post. Not everything we close as off topic here for being a product recommendation question will be automatically on topic for SR.

Answer (score 1):

We don't move things to beta, its just not how its done. [This post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/178444/should-beta-sites-be-listed-for-migration-suggestions) states the reasoning behind it. *If* SR.SE makes it past beta, chances are not all questions you might want to move would make the quality criteria in any case.

That said, if I saw questions that are unwanted here, but would make a great fit there, SR.SE was out of beta, and I'd talked to the relevant mods I'd probably end up flagging it for migration, rather than relying on VTMing

Comment: Since SR.SE made it past beta, how could this question be reactivated, or would it be necessary to make a new thread for this since the status is declined. IMHO, I did see some questions in the last time which would have been worth to migrate. Taken from [Gilles answer](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/858/why-was-my-truecrypt-question-merged-into-a-different-one) *Super User generally rejects recommendation questions (which is the primary reason why the Software Recommendation site exists in the first place), so your question was by no means “perfectly reasonable” there.*