# Migration to Software recommendations as an option during flagging

Tags: discussion, migration

When we flag a question, in the group - off topic - belongs to other stackexchange site there are a few options, but [software recommendations](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/) isn't  inlcuded, however there are a lot of questions should be posted there.

I know the [same question](https://meta.superuser.com/questions/7728/add-softwarerecs-to-vote-to-migrate-option) has been already asked, but that time SR was a beta site, now a lot of time elapsed, we should discuss it again.

Comment: The amount of migration options is limited.  The answer is the same, which site would we give up, to migrate questions to SR.  The fact is the vast amount of questions here that ask for software recommendations would likely be closed for quality reasons over at SR.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There are some key reasons for this.

1. We do not typically migrate questions to beta sites. While it is not specifically stated on Software Recommendations itself, [Area51](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/60887/software-recommendations) does still list the site as in "public beta" as of 2015-10-06. Beta sites are preferred to grow organically to prove that they can survive without content being pushed to them.
   According to [this post](https://softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2298/congratulations-software-recommendations-is-graduating) on SR they are currently in the process of graduating.  Until such time as they are *fully* graduated I would consider the site to not be a "full" migration target.
2. Quality. In all cases migrations are subject to the [golden rule](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/91411/why-was-this-question-closed-as-off-topic-without-being-migrated/91446#91446). A lot of the questions we get are "plz gimme softwre to make blah" which should be closed rather than migrated, opening up the migration path just means that those question are quite likely to be moved rather than outright closed.
3. We only have 5 migration slots, who would we remove to make space for Software Recommendations?

So for me we need at a minimum for Software Recs to be out of beta, but after that we need community consensus on which site we use least for current migrations.

Given that SR *is* graduating though, it would be good to see stats on the current migration targets and whether SR could be a better target.